# How do I account for leap years when mapping to an Ordinal Scale in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

When I map my dates to my x.domain() scale, I am missing the leap year date of "02-29". I tried adding it using this approach:

```
x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.xPos, "02-29"; }));
```

but it just adds it to the end of the array. Another way was to rearrange the CSV file and put a leap year in first. This works but it seems hacky. So I had a look at adding it as follows but got stuck:

```
    // define the x-scale 'manually' using a leap year
        var mindate = new Date(2016,0,1),
            maxdate = new Date(2016,11,31);

   // I then need to set the x.domain but the problem is I want it to be an Ordinal scale
       var x = d3.time.scale()
            .domain([mindate, maxdate])
```

When I get the x.domain() setup properly I then have the problem of scaling non-leap years. How do I add a conditional for a year without a 29 February value, so that the "02-29" x-value is given a corresponding 0 for the y-value?

You can see my blockbuilder [here](http://blockbuilder.org/eoiny/dde8f503ef6ea72edc8f3212896497d7) or my blo.ck [here](http://bl.ocks.org/eoiny/dde8f503ef6ea72edc8f3212896497d7). Notice the stray 02-29 bar for 2016 off to the right..

Comment: `29-Feb-88,0.4` also have this problem? I was born on that day :)

Comment: Happy belated birthday for 2016 then, you must really let loose if you can only celebrate every 4 years!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to ensure that `x.domain()` is set to an array containing **every** date in a typical leap year. I.e. the domain should be

`["01-01", "01-02", ... , "02-28", "02-29", "03-01", ... "12-31"]`

It would mean that every charted year will include the leap day — even non-leap years, in which case that leap day would be bar-less. I'm not sure whether that acceptable for you, but seems reasonable to me.

In order to construct this kind of domain, you need to loop over every day of a leap year (2016 is as good as any) and append it to an array:

```
var leapYearDays = [];// will be populated with all dates
var currentDate = new Date(2016, 0, 1);// the date we'll be incrementing
var safety = 0;// helps prevent infinite looping during development

while(safety < 400 && currentDate.getFullYear() == 2016) {
  leapYearDays.push(formatMth(currentDate));
  currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
  safety++;
}

x.domain(leapYearDays);// apply as the x domain
```

Updated blockbuilder [here](http://blockbuilder.org/anonymous/a929ca600a5205099b4ad64b6dfbf9af).

Comment: @eoin, I just realized I had the wrong link previously. It's updated now, and should illustrate what I proposed above.

Comment: I figured that & updated it from your answer above, cheers:). I still need to somehow enter to a zero placeholder in the 29-Feb for non-leap years? See what happens to my tooltip on this updated blockbuilder [link](http://blockbuilder.org/eoiny/a034d4737c80c55a4cf5a69c7698b9a5) - I can't go past 30-Dec.

Comment: hey upon looking a bit closer at your solution it seems to work perfectly. My current problem is actually an issue with the way I am catching my mousemove event. Thanks again.

Comment: @eoin ok, great. Yeah, I looked into it a bit. Basically, looks like your `mousemove` handler correctly computes date and finds `d`, but needs to handle the cases when d is `null` (either bc it's past the current date in 2016, or when it's on 29 Feb of a non-leap year).

Answer (score 1):

Try out a different approach, there already some functions that can help you get what years are leap years. Such as:

`function leapYear(year){
    return ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0);
}`

then grab the returned value and use an if statement to change the value of maxdate

`if (leapYear(maxdate[0]) && maxdate[1] == 2 && maxdate[2] == 28){
    maxdate = new Date(year, 2 , 29)
}else{
    /* work as usual */
}`

Comment: thanks for the tip I'll check your approach out too, I may have to use it for the second step in my problem - see my comment to @meetamit below.

Comment: I see , what do you mean by a zero placeholder ? 
To fix it we could merge both answers, see meetamit's answer and you could enter that while if the leapYear() function returns true, instead of only 2016 , in that scenario you could add the Feb - 29 when its true and work normally for the non leapYears

Comment: The x.domain().length is now 366 for which the leap year datasets have that many d.rain values, whereas the non-leap year ends up with an 'undefined' at position "02-29". So I think I need to push a d.rain value of 0 into that position for non-leap years to avoid the "TypeError" I get with my tooltip? See the link below.

Comment: I didn't see a link to click. Try to delete the entire value from the x.domain, you can use `splice()` with the values that correspond to 2-29,:

`var indexToRemove = 0;`

`var numberToRemove = 1;`

`arr.splice(indexToRemove, numberToRemove);`

Comment: I'll try that out, thanks. Link [here](http://blockbuilder.org/eoiny/a034d4737c80c55a4cf5a69c7698b9a5)